# ScrollView snapToInterval and snapToAlignment not working for list of text elements

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to recreate a horizontal scroll view similar to the bottom of the Instagram camera. It is a horizontal list of text elements, with each element snapping to the centre as you scroll past it. It allows you to select various camera settings. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

However, I cannot get either snapToInterval or snapToAlignment to work. Instead, the scrollView aligns to flex-start and has no snapping animations. Here is a gif (stying still needs work):

[image]

Here is the full component:

```
'use strict';
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, ScrollView } from 'react-native';

const CameraSlider = () => (
    <View style={styles.sliderViewStyle}>
        <ScrollView
            horizontal
            snapToInterval={100}
            snapToAlignment="center"
            decelerationRate="fast"
        >
            <Text style={styles.textContentStyle}>PHOTO</Text>
            <Text style={styles.textContentStyle}>VIDEO</Text>
        </ScrollView>
    </View>
);

const styles = {
    textContentStyle: {
        color: 'white',
        width: 100,
        fontSize: 16
    },
    sliderViewStyle: {
        height: 40
    }
};

export default CameraSlider;
```

What am I doing wrong? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because the scroll was hitting the edge of the content on the left and you could not scroll any more to the left. There are a few ways around it. One of them being: setting the `contentInset`for left and right. Another way that I've used before is: you need to do some calculations per your needs and just make the most left 'View' have a margin left that allows to scroll the text itself the center as there is still content on the left. Same applies for the most right 'View'.

Here's an example of my code:

```
           <ScrollView
      ref={(scrollView) => { this.scrollView = scrollView; }}
      style={styles.container}
      horizontal
      decelerationRate={0}
      snapToInterval={80}
      pagingEnabled={Platform.OS === 'android'}
      snapToAlignment="center"
      overScrollMode="never"
      scroll
      contentInset={{
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        bottom: 0,
        right: 0,
      }}
    >

      <View style={[styles.view, { backgroundColor: 'red', marginLeft: 160, paddingLeft: 60 }]} />
      <View style={styles.view} />
      <View style={[styles.view, { backgroundColor: 'red' }]} />
      <View style={styles.view} />
      <View style={[styles.view, { backgroundColor: 'red' }]} />
      <View style={[styles.view, { marginRight: 160, paddingRight: 60 }]} />
    </ScrollView>
```

and here's the style I was using for this example:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {},
view: {
marginTop: 100,
backgroundColor: 'blue',
width: 40,
marginLeft: 40,
height: 20,
borderRadius: 10,
// paddingHorizontal : 30
},
});
      <View style={[styles.view, { backgroundColor: 'red' }]} />
      <View style={styles.view} />
      <View style={[styles.view, { backgroundColor: 'red' }]} />
      <View style={[styles.view, { marginRight: 160, paddingRight: 60        }]} />
    </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

I ultimately solved this using a third party library, [react-native-snap-carousel](https://github.com/archriss/react-native-snap-carousel#props-methods-and-getters). I had wanted to avoid doing that, but I couldn't see any other way around it. As of the time of writing, the library looks to be well used and maintained, and the documentation is excellent.

This is what the final code looks like:

```
'use strict';
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import Carousel from 'react-native-snap-carousel';

const SCREEN_WIDTH = Dimensions.get('screen').width;

const MediaTypeSlider = props => {
    const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
        <Text style={styles.textContentStyle}>{item.toUpperCase()}</Text>
    );

    return (
        <View style={styles.sliderViewStyle}>
            <Carousel
                data={props.mediaTypes}
                renderItem={renderItem}
                sliderWidth={SCREEN_WIDTH}
                itemWidth={80}
                itemHeight={50}
                sliderHeight={50}
                onSnapToItem={props.toggleMediaType}
            />
        </View>
    );
};

const styles = {
    textContentStyle: {
        color: 'white',
        width: 80,
        fontSize: 17,
        textAlign: 'center',
        fontWeight: '500'
    },
    sliderViewStyle: {
        height: 50,
        alignItems: 'center'
    }
};

export default MediaTypeSlider;
```

This is it in action:

[image]